# remove files when name does NOT contain some words

Tags: regex, linux, shell, rm

I am using Linux and intend to remove some files using shell.

I have some files in my folder, some filenames contain the word "good", others don't.
For example:

```
ssgood.wmv
ssbad.wmv
goodboy.wmv
cuteboy.wmv
```

I want to remove the files that does NOT contain "good" in the name, so the remaining files are:

```
ssgood.wmv
goodboy.wmv
```

How to do that using `rm` in shell? I try to use

```
rm -f *[!good].*
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean "file **names** contain 'good'"? The example seems to indicate filenames, but you do say the "files contain the word"...

Comment: File *Names* contain good. I am not a native speaker of English. Thanks 4 heads-up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This command should do what you you need:

```
ls -1 | grep -v 'good' | xargs rm -f
```

It will probably run faster than other commands, since it does not involve the use of a regex (which is slow, and unnecessary for such a simple operation).

Comment: +1.  Actually, `grep` is both regex-powered *and* blindingly fast.

Comment: As-is this won't work because the `ls` command lists multiple filenames per line. You need to add the `"-1"` _"one-file-per-line"_ option like so: `ls -1 | grep ...`

Comment: Hmm... On my system `ls` always lists one file per line, so it worked perfectly. Strange, it's probably a default option somewhere. Anyway, I've added the `-1` option so it will always work.

Comment: @EdoDodo: You've probably got an `alias ls='ls -1'` command in one of your startup files.

Comment: This is a horrible method! [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, don't know why it tries to remove the "(standard input)"

Comment: how would you do it recursively ?

Answer (score 6):

With bash, you can get ["negative" matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) via the `extglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*good*)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) with the `-not` operator:

```
find . -not -iname "*good*" -a -not -name "." -exec rm {} \;
```

I've used `-exec` to call `rm` there, but <s>I wonder if `find` has a built-in delete action</s> *it does, see below*.

But ***very*** careful with that. Note in the above I've had to put an `-a -not -name "."` clause in, because otherwise it matched `.`, the current directory. So I'd test thoroughly with `-print` before putting in the `-exec rm {} \;` bit!

**Update**: Yup, I've never used it, but there is indeed a `-delete` action. So:

```
find . -not -iname "*good*" -a -not -name "." -delete
```

Again, be careful and double-check you're not matching more than you want to match first.

Comment: Especially nice suggestion to use `-print` first. :)